# Editing Passthrough SQL Query with Replace in Microsoft Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, pass-through

In Access I have a SQL passthrough query that returns an entire table filtered by first name.

Example

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Original_Data
WHERE first_name = 'Mike';
```

I am trying to write some VBA that on click of a button takes the passthrough query and replaces 'Mike' with any name I put in (this will later be done by a combo box but that's another step).

I have this where TempPT is the name of the passthrough query.

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()

TempPT = Replace(TempPT, "Mike", "Sam")    
DoCmd.OpenQuery "TempPT"

End Sub
```

This doesn't work.

Is there a way that whatever I type in where I have 'Sam' is what the passthrough query will filter by?

I am using passthrough because the DB is huge and clogs up Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the `SQL` property of the query. Probably something like this:

```
With CurrentDb().QueryDefs("TempPT")
    .SQL = Replace(.SQL, "Mike", "Sam") 
End With

DoCmd.OpenQuery "TempPT"
```

Comment: Absolutely smashed it first time.  Thanks a lot dude, plugged this in it works perfectly.  Now to add that combo box in :)